# Logstash omitting daylight saving time when parsing date

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, dst

My log file contains a timestamp without timezone indicator.
In format `dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss`

My server is located in central Europe, so is in timezone UTC+1 but currently uses DST that results in UTC+2.

A date in the log file: `2017-07-25::17:30:00` is parsed as `2017-07-25T16:30:00Z`. But it should be `2017-07-25T15:30:00Z`. As we are in DST now.

Logstash seems to consider only the timezone but not DST.

How can I fix this?

My logstash config:

```
date {
    match => ["logdate", "dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    remove_field => "logdate"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify the timezone your dates are in:

```
date {
    match => ["logdate", "dd-MMM-yyyy::HH:mm:ss"]
    target => "@timestamp"
    remove_field => "logdate"
    timezone => "Europe/Zurich"         <-- add this line
}
```

You may change "Europe/Zurich" to [whatever timezone makes sense to you](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/timezones.html) ([other list of time zones that might be of use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones))